# cambiar opciones de datatable después de haber sido inicializado

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

hola tengo una duda pasa que tengo un datatable al cual luego de que se haya inicializado quiero cambiar una opción que es que una columna no se pueda buscar. tengo el codigo pero no pasa nada. alguien sabe como se podria hacer

```
  //inicializacion del datatable
 table_empresa  = $("#tabla_empresa").DataTable({
                        "scrollY":        "10em",
                        "scrollCollapse": true,
                        "paging":         false,
                        "ajax" : {
                                  "method":"POST",
                                  "url":"controladores/controlador_empresa.php",
                                  "data":{"operacion":"datos"}
                                  },
                        "deferRender" : true,
                        "columns":[
                                   {"data" : "rut"},
                                   {"data" : "razon"},
                                   {"defaultContent":"<button class='btn btn-sm btn-default'>Seleccionar <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></span></button> "}
                                  ],
                       "oLanguage":{
                                    "sUrl": "js/Spanish.json",
                                   }
                      });

//metodo en donde intento cambiar la configuracion pero no funciona

function settings(){
  console.log("entro a settings");
  table_empresa.settings({
                          "columnDefs":[
                          { "searchable": false, "targets":0 }
  ]});
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

viendo tu código, con la consola supongo que ya estas seguro de que entra correctamente a tu función, la solución que yo te propongo es:

```
function settings(){
  console.log("entro a settings");
var table_empresa2 = $('#tabla_empresa').dataTable();
var oSettings = table_empresa2.fnSettings();
oSettings.aoColumns[0].bSearchable = false;
$('#table_empresa').DataTable().ajax.reload();
}
```

Si tienes dudas en cuanto la diferencia entre .dataTable y .DataTable te dejo este link como referencia:

[API DataTable](https://datatables.net/manual/api)

Saludos.

Comment: funciono gracias, pero hay alguna otra forma en la que no se tenga que hacer la llamada ajax, pensado en que si fueran muchos datos seria poco eficiente

Comment: El problema que yo llegue a tener es que hasta que no se recarga la tabla toma en cuenta los cambios  hay una funcion .draw en la tablas jquery pero realmente la vuelve a inicializar, para performance si es que en realidad son muchos registros puedes usar  la paginacion, y cargas parciales o asincronas de la info. https://datatables.net/reference/api/draw() https://datatables.net/reference/option/deferRender https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html